# Codeigniter 4 Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

i have one project in CI3 and update for CI4

i have problem in my template, i receive Call to a member function get() on null.

my view not working call $this->traducao->get('search_string'); please help-me for update in class and libraries

**My Function in Libraries**

```
<?php
namespace App\Libraries;

use Config\Database;


class menus {

  public $listMenus;
  public $listSeo;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->set();

  }

  public function set(){
    $db      = Database::connect();
    $builder = $db->table('menu');
    $query = $builder->where("parente", 0)
                      ->where("ativo", 1)
                      ->orderBy('posicao', 'asc')
                      ->get()->getResultArray();

    if(is_array($query)){
      $menusPai = $query;
    }
    $query2 = $builder->where("parente > 0")
                      ->where("ativo", 1)
                      ->orderBy('posicao', 'asc')
                      ->get()->getResultArray();

     if(is_array($query)){
        $menusFilhos = $query2;
    }
                           
   // $menusFilhos = ($query2->countAllResults() > 0) ? $query2->getResultArray() : false;

    $menus = [];

    foreach ($menusPai as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->listSeo[$value['link']]['pagina_titulo']      = $value['pagina_titulo'];
        $this->listSeo[$value['link']]['pagina_keywords']    = $value['pagina_keywords'];
        $this->listSeo[$value['link']]['pagina_description'] = $value['pagina_description'];

        $menus[$value['id']]['filhos'] = [];
        $menus[$value['id']]['dados']  = $value;

        if ($menusFilhos)
        {
            foreach ($menusFilhos as $k => $v)
            {
                if ($v['parente'] == $value['id'])
                {
                    $this->listSeo[$v['link']]['pagina_titulo']      = $v['pagina_titulo'];
                    $this->listSeo[$v['link']]['pagina_keywords']    = $v['pagina_keywords'];
                    $this->listSeo[$v['link']]['pagina_description'] = $v['pagina_description'];

                    $menus[$value['id']]['filhos'][] = $v;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $this->listMenus = $menus;
  }

  public function get(){
    return $this->listMenus;
  } 

  public function seo($tag){
    $uri = new \CodeIgniter\HTTP\URI();
    print_r($uri);
    $uri = ($this->CI->uri->uri_string() == '') ? '/' : $this->CI->uri->uri_string();

    return $this->listSeo[$uri][$tag];

   // return $this->listSeo[$uri][$tag];
    
  }


}
```

**My ControllerBase**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Libraries\My_parser;
use App\Libraries\Preferencia;
use App\Models\index_model;
use App\Libraries\Traducao;
use App\Libraries\Menus;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $helpers = [];
    public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);
        $this->_db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $this->My_parser = new My_Parser();
        $this->_model = new \App\Models\index_model();
        $this->traducao = new Traducao();
    }

    
      public function output($data, $status){
        $this->output
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
        ->set_output(
          json_encode(
            array(
              'status'=> $status,
              'response'=> $data    
            ), 
            JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES
          )
        )->_display();
        exit;
      }
}
```

**And my view**

```
  <div class="container">
<h2 class="text-center no-m"><?= $this->traducao->get('HOME_EMPRESAS_PARCEIRAS_TITULO') ?></h2>
```

and my index.php loading views layout

```
<?= $this->extend('template/head.php',array('css'=> $css, 'metatags'=> $metatags)) ?>
<?= $this->extend('template/header.php') ?>
<?= $this->extend('template/navbar.php') ?>

<?= $this->section('content')?>
<?= $this->endSection()?>
```

Comment: Can you please post your entire library code? Also post on how you're loading your views

Comment: edited the post and added the information

Comment: Error is originating from 'Traducao' class, so can you update your post with that particular library class?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is it doesn't exist in the View because you never gave it to the View.

`$this->traducao` belongs to the Controller. It may have been constructed with the Controller but there's no immediate reason that any View would have access to it (or *any* data that wasn't passed directly to the View).

All incoming requests should be routed through Controllers; that is their most important purpose. Where is the Controller that's actually handling the request to your `index.php` file?

Any and all Views should be displayed by a Controller because *that* is where you have the ability to pass data (i.e. `$this->traducao`) into the View.

If this is actually CI4 as tagged, then you have a problem with CI3 code still being present as well; for example, `$this->output` isn't used to return Controller responses in CI4, it's `$this->response` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same error when calling the session in the CI4 model call.

```
Solution :

1. define initialize at the top and inside your class.
Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/7-SEckc5XDh9
EX. protected $db;
    protected $session;

    protected function initialize()
    {
        $this->session = session();
        $this->db = db_connect('default');
    }

2. calling step:
syntax : `your protected table`->`method name('string')
EX : $this->session->get('site_language_name')
```